# User Agent not showing in apache2 logs

Tags: apache2, user-agent

As per title, in my apache2 (Apache/2.4.25) logs, the User Agent is not showing.

This is the entry in my `apache2.conf`

```
LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %O \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" combined
```

And in `000-default-le-ssl.conf`

```
CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
```

But the logs appear as follows:

```
xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx - - [14/Dec/2023:10:35:12 +0000] "GET /api/?stuff HTTP/1.0" 200 1990 "-" "-"
```

I'm not sure why it will not show the user agent info? Any pointers?
Many thanks.